# Sort a slice in golang

Tags: sorting, go

I have a slice in golang which looks something like this.

```
list := []TripInfo{
        {
            TripID:  "uuid2",
            infov:true
        },
        {
            TripID:  "uuid1",
            infov:false
        },
    }
```

How can I sort it based on `TripID` so that it looks something like this?

```
list := []TripInfo{
        {
            TripID:  "uuid1",
            infov:false
        },
        {
            TripID:  "uuid2",
            infov:true
        },
    }
```

TripInfo is a struct

```
type TripInfo struct {
    TripUUID  string
    infov bool
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [sort pkg](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#pkg-examples) is your friend:

```
import "sort"

// sort slice in place
sort.Slice(list, func(i, j int) bool {
    return list[i].TripID < list[j].TripID
})
```

[Playground version](https://play.golang.org/p/83XEnUmaqvA).

Comment: @ashish1512 - Any feedback on https://stackoverflow.com/a/60908086/10819573?