# Arrays.sort throws compile-time error 'Anonymous class derived from Comparator..'

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Error:

> Anonymous class derived from Comparator must either be declared
>   Abstract or implement abstract method compare(T,T).

I want to sort the Array based on frequency in the map.

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
        for(int a:arr)
        {
            freq.putIfAbsent(a,freq.getOrDefault(a,0)+1);
        }
Arrays.sort(arr,new Comparator<>(){
            public int compare(int a,int b)
            {
                if(freq.get(b)!=freq.get(a))
                    return freq.get(b)-freq.get(a);
                else
                    return a-b;
            }
        });
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What type is `arr`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an `Integer[]` like

```
Integer[] arr = { 10, 2, 30, 4 };
```

you can do it as follows:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        if (freq.get(b) != freq.get(a))
            return Integer.compare(freq.get(b), freq.get(a));
        else
            return a.compareTo(b);
    }
});
```

In case you have an `int []` like

```
int[] arr = { 10, 2, 30, 4 };
```

convert it into `Integer[]` as

```
Integer[] arr1 = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

and then sort `arr1` as

```
Arrays.sort(arr1, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
        if (freq.get(b) != freq.get(a))
            return Integer.compare(freq.get(b), freq.get(a));
        else
            return a.compareTo(b);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays` does not have a method to sort `int[]` based on a `Comparator`

You could do:

```
    List<Integer> sorted = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().sorted(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {

            if(!Objects.equals(freq.get(b),freq.get(a)))
                return Integer.compare(freq.get(b), freq.get(a));
            else
                return a.compareTo(b);

        }

    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Additional note**: your way of creating the fequency map doesnt work, `putIfAbsent` only adds the first time.

You might want something like that:

```
Map<Integer, Long> fequency = Arrays.stream(ints).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

**Second Additional note**:

Don't use == or != on `Integer`, that might work for some values (>-128 && <127) but is not reliable. You should use `!integer1.equals(integer2)`, or `!Objects.equals(integer1, integer2)`

Comment: Your statement, `Arrays does not have a method to sort int[] based on a Comparator` is wrong. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thats `public static <T> void sort​(T[] a,                            Comparator<? super T> c)` not compatible with int[]

Comment: I didn't realize that you have mentioned about `int[]`. I accidentally read it as `Integer[]`.

Comment: Also added the recomendations from Andreas regarding usage `Integer.compare` and `Integer.compareTo`